# Stable curves over non-noetherian schemes

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, moduli-spaces

In their seminal paper *The irreducibility of the space of curves of a given genus*, Deligne and Mumford define a stable curve of genus $g$ over a scheme $S$ to be a flat, proper morphism $X\to S$, all of whose geometric fibres are stable curves of arithmetic genus $g$. I want to know **is a stable curve over $S$ always locally of finite presentation?** (This is true when $S$ is noetherian; I'm interested in the non-noetherian case.)

Some context:

The reason I ask is that the [Stacks Project](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0C58) defines a family of nodal curves to be a flat, *locally finitely presented* morphism $X\to S$, all of whose fibres are nodal curves. I was curious why the assumption of local finite presentation seemed to be necessary  in the definition of a family of nodal curves, but not in the definition of stable curves. Moreover, for families of nodal curves, [pathologies](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/05LB) can occur, such as a flat, proper morphism $X\to S$, all of whose fibres are nodal curves, but which is not locally finitely presented.

I should say that Deligne and Mumford assert that because $X\to S$ is flat and its geometric fibres are local complete intersections, then $X\to S$ is a locally complete intersection morphism, in particular is locally finitely presented. But I do not understand the argument.

Comment: You said it all: the definition in D-M is not the right one, and is not the definition they use, e.g. for the complete intersection property you pointed out. In fact, Proposition (5.1) ($\mathscr{M}_g$ is separated of finite type over $\mathbb{Z}$) *implies* that stable curves are finitely presented!
For your specific question, you get easy counterexamples from the Stack Project examples you mention.

Comment: https://www.math.columbia.edu/~dejong/wordpress/?p=1117

Comment: @gdb: Thanks for this link! De Jong's "wild guess" is very intriguing. And I had overlooked the fact that the genus is assumed constant. 
Of course I agree with the last paragraph in the blog: the right definition should include finite presentation even if the wild guess is correct.

Comment: I concur with your comments -- it does seem like the words "finitely presented" should be included in the definition, even if perhaps they are implied (very non-obviously!) by the other conditions. Thanks for the comments, this has really cleared this up for me!